# XmlTextWriter: How to write new line when I want, not Indented?

Tags: c#, xml

I know how to use Formatting.indented, but I don't want it because that will write each element in a new line. What I want is to insert new line only before specific elements. In other words, I want to control exactly when new line is made.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`WriteWhitespace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter.writewhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(Console.Out))
{
    writer.WriteStartElement("root");
    writer.WriteStartElement("child");
    writer.WriteWhitespace("\n");
    writer.WriteStartElement("child-on-new-line");
    writer.WriteString("content");
    writer.WriteEndElement();
    writer.WriteEndElement();
    writer.WriteEndElement();
}
```

This will output:

```
<root><child>
<child-on-new-line>content</child-on-new-line></child></root>
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SqyFBU).

Answer (score -1):

White-spaces are a don't care in xml.  Don't worry about it.  It is much easier to use xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication42
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XElement book = new XElement("book", new object[] {
                new XElement("title","Pride And Prejudice")
            });

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: He said that he doesn't want the whitespace. This doesn't answer op question. I won't down vote because you are right but this is not an answer.